# If FB.init({status:true}) causes the Javascript SDK to load status, how can I get the status?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, status

If `FB.init({status:true})` causes the Javascript SDK to load status, what is the most efficient way I can get the status?

Do I have to use the async call to `FB.getLoginStatus()`?  Or is there a synchronous way to get the status that would save a web request?

Comment: you could log the user in server side.

Comment: True, however, in my case the content is static HTML and all the interactivity is on the browser using the Javascript SDK. Even if I run scripting on the server, then it would slow down response time for the page to be served, would it not? And even then the Javascript wouldn't know the status and he would have to make his own call to the API anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using JavaScript, then the only way is to make `FB.getLoginStatus()` call. However, if you are worried about, say, slow response time, then you could simply save the status in a cookie once a successful authorization process is completed.

Though, since we are talking about milliseconds, I would discourage you from going that way.

Comment: To add to this, the response of `getLoginStatus` is now cached by the FB SDK

Comment: Since then, I have developed https://github.com/gajus/fuss.js, which is an abstraction around fb.js that provides more intuitive API.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to retrieve the status is subscribing to the `auth.authRepsonseChange` event.

example:

```html
var auth_response_change_callback = function(response) {
    console.log("auth_response_change_callback");
    console.log(response);
};

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', auth_response_change_callback);
```

Source: [FB event documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.10)